# Error when trying to add db2 column between 2 columns

Tags: db2, alter

I am trying to add a new column between 2 existing columns. Here I am using "after" clause to insert the new column. Below is my query.

```
   alter table doc add column alt_title varchar(10) after title;
```

I am seeing the below error

```
An unexpected token "title" was found following "varchar(10) after".  
Expected tokens may include:  "REFERENCES".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.8.86
Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 0 ms.
```

I even tried before clause,and get same results. Can someone please help me fix the issue?

Comment: Neither `before` or `after` is valid syntax for DB2. I cannot imagine why someone would care about the column position in the DDL, but if you do you'll need to drop the table and create it again with the new column where you want it.

Comment: @mustaccio The order in the column is important in order to reduce the log usage: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0024496.html

Comment: @AngocA -- by the way the question is asked, I doubt very much that the OP is after logging optimization. After all, the **VARCHAR** column is being added **in the middle** of the table.

Comment: @mustaccio It is true that the question seems more like the column order for a "select *", however, as answerers as we are, we have to provide open answers. This question could help others to improve performance, and the varchar in the middle could help to reduce the logging if that column does not change when updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to modify the table by adding a column in the middle, however you can recreated with the good structure.

- You create a second table, with the same quantity of columns of the first table with the desired order.
- You perform a insert select by providing the column names.
- You add the constraints of the first column in the second one.
- You drop constraints in the first table.
- Finally, you rename tables

You can get all this information by using db2look.

Comment: Depends on the version and release of DB2..  DB2 for IBM i v7.1 and higher support the `BEFORE` clause.

Comment: @Charles I did not know that. Sound interesting.

Comment: It could be possible (I have not tried) to use ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE, by specifying the DDL in the 9th column: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-0-17